# How to make an pdo_sqlite connection from binary stream in PHP

Tags: php, sqlite, pdo

Having a .sqlite file in a memory stream (php://memory), I want to pipe it to pdo_sqlite driver to create a connection. Is this possible?

Its for testing purposes, I want to recreate DBs quickly without recreate schema at each time nor using tmpfs.

Answer (score 0):

In memory sqlite has some limitations. The memory space could be the request, the session, but no way seems documented to share a base in memory among users.

For a request, open your base with the code

```
$pdo = new PDO( 'sqlite::memory:');
```

and your base will disapear on next request.

For session persistency

```
<?php 
$pdo = new PDO( 
    'sqlite::memory:', 
    null, 
    null, 
    array(PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT => true) 
); 
?>
```

Also read  [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-sqlite.connection.php)

Comment: Hi, Saty! Yes, but It doesnt work for me. I need to read a .sqlite file already populated with data, and clone it at runtime in each test case (phpunit). So, I dont want to use the filesystem, but this memory-based solution is not  what I want